# php artisan serve command works but url not working

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.4,

After running php artisan serve command fresh laravel setup works on this url `localhost:8000` but when i try to access with public url `localhost/lara54/public`. it is not working and gives white blank page. I tried this using virtual host in linux giving folder path upto public but still not working.

php artisan serve command also creates a virtual host what i am missing here to make this setup work with URL.

Comment: did you got any solution, I am using laravel 5.8 and facing same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command it will work

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

give permission to following two directories:

```
storage

bootstrap/cache
```

i hope its help you

Comment: Already done because this is the part of installation process.

Comment: please check your .env file's APP_KEY and APP_URL

Comment: APP_KEY=base64:Nic9q7V1p8aiQg9HtZdzIjtBwMxNuU3XDoBs5Gd6Tz0=

Comment: APP_URL=localhost/lara54/public

Comment: not working, changed to localhost and ran config:cache command.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following --port param:

```
php artisan serve --port=8000
```

Hope it helps you because this solves my problem.

Comment: php artisan serve is already working here. He asked for public URL.

Answer (score 1):

I just got inspired by **user4535674**'s and **Bercove**'s answers.

Instead of
`php artisan serve --port=8000`
type
`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000`

It worked in my case like a charm!

Comment: You could even use the undocumented `SERVER_PORT` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The default Laravel command "`php artisan server`" returns the URL "localhost:8000" in your browser address bar, so you should type  "http://localhost:8000".
Because it uses the default PHP built-in web server (read at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)) to serve the Laravel application direcory for development.

For production, it is recommended to use nginx or Apache, you may read on DigitalOcean [for Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) or [for Apache](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost)

Answer (score 0):

Try install vc runtime
Work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of fact  that serve command and run with public folder give url not found error.
There are three ways

1. you should change your url like this:

```html
<a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}">
```

2. you should change your .htaccess file and add code

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. on production server you should run VC